# Jquery hover meny delay hiding on mouseleave but stop the hide if mouse enters before the timelimit

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, delay

Im trying to add a delay that works on my dropdown menu if the person misstakly
moves mouse outside the menu. I have tried many solutions found on here but non of them
seam to work.

Edit:
here is the link to [jsfiddle for a complite example](http://jsfiddle.net/hN7FB/8/)

Edit: 5

```
$(function () {
            var slideDownTime = 400;
            var firstRun = true;

            var $menu = $('#menu'),
            $submenus = $menu.find('ul'),
            $items = $menu.find('li'),
            hide = function ($el, $instantHide) {
                if (!firstRun) {
                    if (!$instantHide) {
                        // force the menu item to show.
                        $el.css({ visibility: "visible", display: "block" });

                        var hideMenuId = setTimeout(function () {
                            $el.hide().css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        }, 5000);

                        $el.data('hideMenuId', hideMenuId);
                    } else {
                        $el.hide().css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    }
                } else {
                    $el.hide().css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
            },
            show = function ($el) {
                clearTimeout($el.data('hideMenuId'));
                $el.css('visibility', 'visible').stop(1, 1).slideDown(slideDownTime);

                hide($el.parent().siblings().find("ul"), true); // <-- this line hides the other submenus if hovered.

                var singleLevel = $el.parent().find("ul > li:not(:has(ul)) > a");
                singleLevel.hover(function () {
                    hide($(this).closest("ul").children('li').not(this).find("ul"), true);
                }, function () {
                });

                firstRun = false;
            };

            $menu.focusout(hide($submenus));
            $items.hover(function () {
                show($(this).children('ul'));
            }, function () {
                hide($(this).children('ul'), false);
            });

             // find the root elemement level with no children.
             $menu.find("> li a").not("ul li ul a").not("li:has(ul) > a").hover(function () {
                  //hide the unwantend menu items.
                  hide($(this).closest("ul").children('li').not(this).find("ul"), true);
            }, function () {
            });

 });
```

Ok this is what i ended up with.
but can this not be made with less code ?

Edit: 6
The jsfiddle link is now updated to the latest verision.

Comment: Can you put up an example at jsfiddle? And also the timer code...

Comment: what timer code? the only timer code i can think of is the setTimeout with 1000 miliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `focusout()` with a `delay()`. Also, I don't think you need all that `if else` logic. Every submenu is an `<ul>` children of `$('#menu')` and at the same time, children of a `<li>`, so you can easily create a function to show or hide a menu which accepts a jQuery object as parameter. Without your html code I can't say for sure, but something like this should work. Adapt to your needs.

```
var $menu = $('#menu'), // Assuming this is a `<ul>`
    $submenus = $menu.find('ul'),
    $items = $menu.find('li'),
    hide = function($el){ 
        $el.delay(500).hide().css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    },
    show = function($el){ 
        $el.css('visibility', 'visible').stop(1, 1).slideDown(); 
    };

$menu.focusout(hide($submenus));
$items.hover(function(){
    show($(this).children('ul'));
}, function(){
    hide($(this).children('ul'));
});
```

Also this:

```
element.css('visibility') != "visible" && element.css('display') != "block"
```

is the same as:

```
element.is(':visible')
```

Comment: i tested youre example but it wont stop the menu from hidding when mouseing it out it goes away right away. the delay(500) sould not that make an delay before it calls hide ? i tested with delay 5000 for 5 secound but still it goes away before that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at hoverIntent plugin. All you will need to do is include it and change your "hover" method to "hoverIntent"

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: i have already tested that but dident get it to work as far as the jsfiddle example